# Асинхронная репликация mysql, какой форк выбрать?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, репликация

Необходимо географическое распределение базы данных mysql(master-master).

Про сравнение форков для синхронной репликации я прочитал много, и понял что выбор строится скорее между percona и mariadb, так как mariadb разрабатывается не коммерческой организацией и требует отключение селинукса, при прочих ~равных отзывах я бы первой попробовал внедрить percona.

Но для решения географически распределённой репликации нужна асинхронная, я так думаю, а по этой теме я не могу найти хорошего сравнения. Подозреваю что модифицированные innodb хранилища у форков всё равно дадут лучшую производительность и стабильность работы.

Меня сильнее производительности беспокоит консистентность данных. У меня уже есть небольшой опыт внедрения асинхронной oracle mysql master-master с GTID, я настроил её в экспериментальных целях на проекте с посещаемостью в ~600 уников в сутки, на одной виртуалке развернув 2 контейнера БД. Посетителей мало, но у CMS 1С Битрикс есть часто изменяемая таблица с пользовательскими сессиями и раз в 2-4 дня мне приходит письмо что в этой таблице 1032, 1062. Для этой таблицы консистентность значения не имеет, ок, но что будет на проекте с ~40т и например таблицами веб форм хз.

Прошу поделитесь пожалуйста вашим опытом внедрения асинхронной mysql. Отдельно приветствуется история и про синхронную.:)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Обычно таблицы и пользовательскими сессиями исключают из репликации.

[Цитата](https://habrahabr.ru/company/bitrix/blog/147098/):

> Почти в любом проекте есть некритичные для потери или восстанавливаемые данные. В том числе — и в базе данных.

В нашем случае такими данными были сессии. Что было плохого в том, что реплицировалось все подряд?

В таблицах сессий наряду с SELECT'ами много операций записи (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`). Это значит, что мы даем лишнюю нагрузку на slave базу. Ту нагрузку, которую можно избежать.

Кроме того, при достаточно большом значении `query_cache_size` мы столкнулись с тем, что активная работа с этими таблицами и их участие в репликации приводят к тому, что многие треды «подвисают» в состоянии «waiting for query cache lock» (видно в `SHOW PROCESSLIST`). Далее это чревато повышенной нагрузкой на CPU и общей деградацией производительности.

Исключение этих данных из репликации полностью решило проблему"